# validate and submit multiple forms

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a single page on which I have log in form, registration form and forgot password form. I could validate and submit log in form successfully, but when I tried to validate the registration form, it simply got submitted and did not validate. Can I validate multiple forms in a single page using jquery ? If we can how ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it. I was using different js files to validate each form separately. I moved all the code to single file and all forms were validated. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible. Apparently you forgot to attach the validator to other forms than only the first one.